# How to read a sub-sample of partitioned parquets using pySpark?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Assume I am provided the following partition of parquets data:

```
.
└── data/
    ├── product=soda/
    │   ├── <hash>_toto.parquet
    │   ├── ...
    │   └── <hash>.parquet
    └── product=cake/
        ├── <hash>.parquet
        └── ...
```

I would like to read the data using PySpark but by excluding a given list of parquets which contains `<hash>_toto.parquet`.

I can read the whole partitioned data but I have no idea how to exclude some of them. I would like to keep the feature that Spark implements to merge the data and create a column `product` here with the following code :

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext
# this code read all parquets, merge them, and create a column product
spark = SparkSession.builder \
                    .master("local") \
                    .appName("app") \
                    .config("spark.executor.memory", "5gb") \
                    .config("spark.cores.max", "6") \
                    .getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
dataframe = sqlContext.read.parquet("./data")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`input_file_name`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.input_file_name.html) function to filter out rows coming from files containing `'hash'` in filename:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = sqlContext.read.parquet("./data")

df = df.filter(~F.input_file_name().rlike('hash'))
```

Comment: As said in the post, I would like to read the data using PySpark but by excluding a given list of parquets which contains `<hash>_toto.parquet`. So not only this parquet, but a given **list of parquets**. Your answer is almost correct :) I am going to find which function I can use after `input_file_name` to exclude a list of paths.

Comment: @Mistapopo `rlike` function should work for multiple patterns to exclude. just use regex `rlike('pattern1|pattern2|...')`

Answer (score 0):

You could add a boolean column `toto` into your dataframe and `partitionBy('toto')`. Then you get subfolders toto=True/ and toto=False/.

After reading the complete folder you can then simply run `.where('toto == False') to prevent Spark from reading these parquets.